# bigcommerceSigned.verifyJWT is not a function nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt, bigcommerce

When I am trying to follow the bigCommerce's tutorials, I am getting this error.

Tutorial : https://github.com/bigcommerce/sample-app-nodejs/tree/step-2-connect-app-to-bc

> {"message":"bigcommerceSigned.verifyJWT is not a function"}

```
import * as BigCommerce from 'node-bigcommerce';

// Create BigCommerce instance
// https://github.com/bigcommerce/node-bigcommerce/
const bigcommerce = new BigCommerce({
    logLevel: 'info',
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callback: process.env.AUTH_CALLBACK,
    responseType: 'json',
    headers: { 'Accept-Encoding': '*' },
    apiVersion: 'v3'
});

const bigcommerceSigned = new BigCommerce({
    secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    responseType: 'json'
});

interface QueryParams {
    [key: string]: string;
}

export function getBCAuth(query: QueryParams) {
    return bigcommerce.authorize(query);
}

export function getBCVerify({ signed_payload_jwt }: QueryParams) {
    return bigcommerceSigned.verifyJWT(signed_payload_jwt);
}
```

The code I am using on lib/auth.ts

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That was fixed when I use the predefined versions by bigCommerce

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

On package.json I've used this and it worked:

```
 "node-bigcommerce": "github:bigcommerce/node-bigcommerce",
```

Apparently this "version" has the `verifyJWT`  function.